# How to have multiple parameters for body in Swagger

Tags: rest, wcf, swagger

So I'm having problem with how I pass my data.

This is my WCF rest method

```
  [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetCustomFieldValues",
            Method = "POST",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        Dictionary<string, Object> GetCustomFieldValues(string pwaUrl, string projectUid, List<string> customFieldNames);
```

On Swagger this is my declaration for it

```
/GetCustomFieldValues:
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: Param
          in: body
          description: The custom field value you want to get
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/GetCustomFieldValues"
      responses:
        200:
          description: Getting custom field value using name
      summary: GetCustomFieldValues
      description: GetCustomFieldValues
      operationId: GetCustomFieldValues 
definitions:
  GetCustomFieldValues:
    type: object
    properties: 
      pwaUrl:
        type: string
      projectUid:
        type: string 
      customFieldNames:
        type: array 
        items: 
          type: string
```

When I used my Advanced Rest Client or Powershell the method works, the only difference is how I assemble the body.

For Swagger I need to use a definition since I can't do multiple parameters on body.

I'm also putting this at the top of the swagger

```
schemes:
  - http
consumes: 
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird thing about WCF,

CORS needs to be both Global.asx and web.config, this works on mine
[CORS enabled but response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 when POSTing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258959/cors-enabled-but-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404-when-po)