# Ionicview and ionic serve CORS

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, ionic-view

My ionic app is connecting to asp.net web api on azure. The API already allow all origin to access and the API_KEY header. However I am still getting Message
"The origin 'http://localhost:8100' is not allowed." on both Ionic serve and ionic view

Code in ionic app

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('API_KEY', 'X-some-key');
headers.delete("Origin");
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
return this.http.get(url, options);
```

request and response header when using ionic serve
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer from here : [CORS enabled but response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 when POSTing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258959/cors-enabled-but-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404-when-po)

The problem is backend doesn't have OPTIONS handler, added OPTIONS handler in web.config works.