# CORS error with Windows Authentication in Web API

Tags: cors, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

Here is my setup in Web API

```
void ConfigureServices(WebApplicationBuilder webApplicationBuilder)
{
webApplicationBuilder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
webApplicationBuilder.Services.AddAuthorization();

ConfigureGenericServices(webApplicationBuilder.Services);
ConfigureCors(webApplicationBuilder.Services);
   
}

void ConfigureCors(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("NTLMPolicy",
        policyBuilder =>
        {
            policyBuilder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7117")
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});
```

}

I am calling the endpoints from Blazor App. HTTPGET calls are working fine but HTTPPOST calls are not working.

Here is my sample code calling POST end point

```
 public async Task<bool> SaveCartItem(SaveCartItemRequest request)
{
 var serializeRequest = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
 var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "Cart/SaveCartItem")
 {
     Content = new StringContent(serializeRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
 };
 requestMessage.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);

 var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
 return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
```

}

What am I doing wrong?[image: Error]

Comment: You probably looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130623/asp-net-core-web-api-using-windows-authentication-cors-request-unauthorised  have a try to allow anonymous CORS preflight checks.